# Process sensitivity list vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I have the following problem:

I have a simple entity driven by a single process:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;            
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;        
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.ALL;

entity somma_CDC is
                Port 
                    (
                    
                        A                       : in    std_logic;                                  
                        B                       : in    std_logic;                                  
                        Reset                   : in    std_logic;                                  
                        Internal_Carry_enable   : in    std_logic;                                  
                        S                       : out   std_logic                                   
                    
                    );
end somma_CDC;

architecture Behavioral_somma_CDC of somma_CDC is

signal Internal_Carry: std_logic;

begin
    somma_CDC:process (Reset,A,B) 
                    begin
                    
                        if Reset = '1' 
                            then
                                Internal_Carry <= '0';
                                
                        else 
                                S <= A XOR B XOR Internal_Carry ;
                                if (Internal_Carry_enable = '1')
                                    then
                                    Internal_Carry <= (A AND B) OR (Internal_Carry AND A) OR (Internal_Carry AND B) ;
                                end if;
                        end if;
                        
                    end process;
end architecture;
```

In practice, it is very similar to a full adder.
Ideally, the block diagram should look like this:

[image: pic.]

My problem arises when in the cycles following the first, I find the values of the operands equal. In this case, the process does not activate and therefore fails to calculate the case in which
A = 1, B = 1, Carry_In = 1.
There is a clock signal in my system, but the clock goes faster than the input data change. If I put the clock in the sensitivity list I get wrong results, as the carry "propagates" in the wrong way.
I tried without using the sensitivity list and putting a wait for "X" time, with "X" the minimum time for changing operands A and B. It works, but it depends on something that can always change in a project.
Is there another way to activate this process?

Comment: I can't see your picture. Is this supposed to be combinational or sequential logic? If it's combinational, you have combinational feedback. If it's sequential, where's the clock?  Please submit a [mcve].

Comment: Your code shows no clock, and the process is missing signals from the sensitivity list. Wait times are not synthesisable. What are the goals? Are you targetting an FPGA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR:
Add Internal_Carry to your sensitivity list.

Edit: As @Tricky pointed out, Internal_Carry_enable should be in the sensitivity list as well.

Full Answer:

I think the problem here is that you may miss understood how to use the sensitivity list. You are using it as C like programming, where the process would be reading reset, A and B as inputs.

But in vhdl every signal in the sensitivity list is a trigger that must change its value in order for the process to be rerun again.

So, the main problem here is the signal Internal_Carry. Since it is not in the sensitivity list, the signal S wont respond as Internal_Carry change to a new value after the first run. You would need to change either reset, A or B to see the effects of Internal_Carry from the last run.

There are other problems in your code, but not related to this.

1. Internal_Carry is a latch since you didnt assign any default value to it (which value should it holds if reset is not 0 and Internal_Carry_enable is not 1?).
2. You may need to take a look in the differences between combinational and sequential logic, since you wrote about clock in an adder circuit. If you add a clock the assignment of a value to a signal will generate a register, while a process without a clock in its sensitivity list will be purely combinational.

Comment: `Internal_Carry_enable` needs to also be in the sensitivity list

Comment: @Tricky you're right, I'm going to edit my answer with the updated info